# Bizspark, Transfer azure vm to another account

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, bizspark

I have a bizspark subscription and one of the accounts has reached its billing limits(there are multiple vms on this account).so I want to transfer a vm from that account to another so that the billing is balanced and no account reaches its spending limits.
what is the simplest way of achieving this task. If there is another solution without transferring that would be great as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this question? My team is seeing a similar situation.

Comment: No I didnt and I was on a deadline so took a dump of the db and backup the code and redeployed using another account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this multiple times, every time I contact the support and they do it for me with no problem, they may ask you for some steps to do before they start the migration.
I found this is the best way to do it and the most safe way at least because I am not good in azure administration.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do exactly the same. It took me almost a day to figure out all the steps so I think it will be useful to share my experience.

I would recommend signing in with the source and destination accounts in two different browsers while you are following the steps. Otherwise, you will have to sign in/sign out several times in order to switch the accounts.

First of all *the source and destination subscriptions must exist within the same Azure Active Directory tenant* in order to move resources between them. So if you previously haven't moved them in one directory now you have to do it. In my case, I moved the destination subscription to the source subscription directory.

1. Go to the [Classic Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com) for the source account. Go to `Active Directory`. Select `Default Directory` from the list. Go to the `Users` tab and click `Add User`. On the `Tell us about this user` dialog choose value for `Type of user` (I've selected `User with an Existing Microsoft account`),  then fill the account and click click `Next`. On the next screen fill the name and choose the role (in my case `Global Admin`). Click the `Complete` button. (Now if you go back to the new portal (`Azure Active Directory -> Overview`), the newly added user should be available in the default directory)
2. Still in the classic portal. Go to `Settings -> Subscriptions`. Select the subscription and click `Edit Directory`. On the `Change the associated directory` dialog select the directory of the source subscription and click `Next`. On the second screen click `Complete`.  Now both subscriptions are in the same Azure Active Directory tenant. You are *almost* ready.
3. Go to the new portal for the destination account. Refresh the page (or even sign out/sing in if needed) and now when you open the account menu in the upper-right corner you should see on the bottom of the menu the two directories. The default directory of the destination subscription is selected. Select the other to switch to it.
4. Go to `Subscriptions`. You should see the destination subscription (that is now in the Azure Active Directory of the source account).
   You need to give permissions to the source account so it could move resources to the destination subscription (this wasn't obvious to me). Select the subscription from the list and go to `Access Control (IAM)`.  Click `Add` from the toolbar. In the `Add permissions` panel that appears, choose the role (in my case `Owner`) and select the source account (should be listed here). Click `Save`.
5. Go to the portal for the source account. Go to `Subscriptions` - you should see both subscriptions. Now you can move your resources between them.
6. Select the virtual machine you want to move. Click `Move -> Move to another subscription` from the toolbar. In the blade that will open, choose the destination subscription from the Subscription combo box, then choose existing or create a new resource group and click `OK`. That's it.